# Angular 11 HTTP POST to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, angular, post

I am trying to post my inputs to my SQL Server database. I can in fact `POST` to the database, but I get back a blank response. I know it's because I am returning "Success" instead of my variables but how to I correctly format that for the return statement?

**POST method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Post(Weather Wea)
{
    string query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.Information (Date, TemperatureC, TemperatureF, Summary) VALUES ('" + Wea.Date + @"'
                    ,'" + Wea.TemperatureC + @"'
                    ,'" + Wea.TemperatureF + @"'
                    ,'" + Wea.Summary + @"'
                    )";

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("WeatherAppCon");

    SqlDataReader myReader;

    using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        myCon.Open();

        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
        {
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            table.Load(myReader); 

            myReader.Close();
            myCon.Close();
        }
    }

    return new JsonResult("Success");
}
```

**Front-end POST**

```
export class PostDataComponent {
  baseUrl: string;
  date: number;
  temperatureC: number;
  summary: string;
  weatherForm: FormGroup;
  

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.baseUrl = "https://localhost:44347/WeatherForecast";
    this.weatherForm = formBuilder.group({
      Date: new FormControl(),
      TemperatureC: new FormControl(),
      Summary: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  CreateData() {
    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: {
        'date': this.weatherForm.value.Date.toString(),
        'temperatureC': this.weatherForm.value.TemperatureC.toString(),
        'summary': this.weatherForm.value.Summary.toString()
      }
    });
    
    console.log(params);
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl, {},{ params: params }).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things here.

- As marc_s commented, you should be using parameterization instead of concatenating to avoid any potential SQL injection:

```
    string query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.Information (Date, TemperatureC, TemperatureF, Summary) VALUES (@Date, @TemperatureC, @TemperatureF, @Summary)";
    
    ...
    
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Wea.Date);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemperatureC", Wea.TemperatureC);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemperatureF", Wea.TemperatureF);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", Wea.Summary);
    ...
```

- Unless you have a trigger on your target table with an output, your query isn't returning any data (just the number of rows inserted) and your `SqlDataReader` is empty. You could get rid of the reader/`DataTable` and use `myCommand.ExecuteScalar()` instead in this case. If you do have a trigger outputting the inserted data, disregard this.
- If you don't have an output trigger but do still need to return the inserted values for whatever reason, you could keep your `SqlDataReader` and update your query to the following

```
    string query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.Information (Date, TemperatureC, TemperatureF, Summary)
        OUTPUT inserted.Date,inserted.TemperatureC,inserted.TemperatureF,inserted.Summary
        VALUES (@Date, @TemperatureC, @TempreatureF, @Summary)";
```

- Without knowing the response format you're looking for, it's hard to give an answer on how to generate it. If you need to return the inserted values, you could use the OUTPUT keyword as in the previous bullet and serialize your `DataTable`.

Comment: I probably should have added my POST Component to make this a bit easier to understand what I'm trying to do. Perhaps the edit above will help.

Comment: Definitely good to include, but it looks like you're just printing the response to the console. What do you actually want to see when that `console.log(data)` happens? Ex: If you just need to verify that your insert happened successfully, `ExecuteScalar()` would return the number rows inserted as an int, so you could conditionally output `JsonResult("Success")` if that int is >0 else `JsonResult("Failed")`.

Comment: I want to POST my variable values, Date, TemperatureC, and Summary to my dbo.Information table inside my WeatherTemplate Database. I have my connection string setup correctly. Shouldn't I be returning my variables though--- not "Success"? I'm not sure how my database is supposed to receive my values unless I return them in the API POST method.

Comment: As long as the form data is making it into your POST method and the code in your `using (SqlConnection...` executes, it will insert into your database. If it's not working, I'd recommend putting a debug point at the start of your POST method and stepping through it to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The parameterized query '(@Date int,@TemperatureC int,@TemperatureF int,@Summary nvarchar' expects the parameter '@Summary', which was not supplied.

This is is the error I am receiving the problem from is this line  myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Try this: `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", String.IsNullOrEmpty(Wea.Summary) ? DBNull.Value : Wea.Summary);`. You might need to handle all 4 like that if they can come in without values.

Comment: The program is having a build error. 

Feature 'feature' is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or greater. 

How do I update C# in Visual Studio?

Comment: Okay I fixed it and I can POST now but after POSTing my database table values received are 0 for each variable.